# How can I load a folders files into a ListView?

Tags: c#, listview, file

I'd like to have a user select a folder with the FolderBrowserDialog and have the files loaded into the ListView.

My intention is to make a little playlist of sorts so I have to modify a couple of properties of the ListView control I'm assuming. What properties should I set on the control?

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Surely you just need to do the following:

```
    FolderBrowserDialog folderPicker = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (folderPicker.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        ListView1.Items.Clear();

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPicker.SelectedPath);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {

            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(fileName);
            item.Tag = file;

            ListView1.Items.Add(item);

        }

    }
```

Then to get the file out again, do the following on a button press or another event:

```
    if (ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {

        ListViewItem selected = ListView1.SelectedItems[0];
        string selectedFilePath = selected.Tag.ToString();

        PlayYourFile(selectedFilePath);

    }
    else
    {
        // Show a message
    }
```

For best viewing, set your ListView to Details Mode:

```
ListView1.View = View.Details;
```

Answer (score 3):

A basic function could look like this:

```
    public void DisplayFolder ( string folderPath )
    {
        string[ ] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles( folderPath );

        for ( int x = 0 ; x < files.Length ; x++ )
        {
            lvFiles.Items.Add( files[x]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

List item

private void buttonOK_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {

        DirectoryInfo FileNm = new DirectoryInfo(Application.StartupPath);
        var filename = FileNm.GetFiles("CONFIG_*.csv");
        //Filename CONFIG_123.csv,CONFIG_abc.csv,etc

       foreach(FileInfo f in filename)
        listViewFileNames.Items.Add(f.ToString());

    }
```